# How does one use Annotation from an ARRAY of CLLocationCoordinate2D using the new iOS 17 MapKit APIs?

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

I need to overlay ***thousands of annotations*** onto a MapKit map.  Their last stop before being mapped will be in an array of structs like the one shown below.

I can't seem to figure out how to embed the `Map` `Annotation` into a loop that the `Map` will accept.

### Here is my code *(which correctly displays ONE annotation)*...

```swift
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MyAnnotation: Identifiable {
   let id = UUID()
   let name: String
   let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
   let color: Color
   let score: Double
}

struct JunkMapView: View {
   
   let annotations = [
      MyAnnotation(name: "9", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.2926854029081, longitude: -71.0679634411345), color: .yellow, score: 10),
      MyAnnotation(name: "8", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.4281694052464, longitude: -71.1093263739832), color: .orange, score: 7.2),
      MyAnnotation(name: "7", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.3717488333676, longitude: -71.0670886507071), color: .red, score: 3.46)
   ]
   
   
   var body: some View {
      Text("Hello, World!")
      
      Map {
         Annotation("", coordinate: annotations[1].coordinate, anchor: .bottom) {
            HStack{
               Image(systemName: "flame.circle")
                  .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
                  .foregroundStyle(annotations[1].color, .blue)
                  .font(.system(size: 100, weight: .thin))
                  .padding(4)
                  .background(.clear)
               Text("\(annotations[1].score)")
            }
         }
      }
   }
}


#Preview {
   JunkMapView()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this approach using a `ForEach` loop to display all your annotations:

```
  Map {
      ForEach(annotations) { p in
          Annotation("", coordinate: p.coordinate) {
              HStack{
                 Image(systemName: "flame.circle")
                    .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
                    .foregroundStyle(p.color, .blue)
                    .font(.system(size: 100, weight: .thin))
                    .padding(4)
                    .background(.clear)
                 Text("\(p.score)")
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Perfect!, Thank you, I new I was close but couldn't close the gap. :-)